# Elements of a horror musical song?

Tags: composition, rhythm, harmony, chord-progressions, melody

When composing horror music for musical drama in general, what does one need to consider as in harmony, melody and rhythm, etc.?
For harmony, I am especially interested in what chords are normally used as the root, what chord progressions are common and what special chords(all types of diminished, etc.) are typically used.
For melody, I am particularly interested in what scales are normally used to compose the melody (including non-traditional scales such as various pentatonic scales, etc.).
Lastly, for rhythm, I am curious about whether any particular form of rhythm is common and what meter is common.

Comment: don't innovate, duplicate: http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2014/05/08/dies_irae_in_movies_tom_allen_and_the_cbc_trace_the_history_of_the_latin.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm sure someone more experienced will come to help, but for now, here are some suggestions:

- Make use of dissonant chords. In particular, augumented fifths, and [diminished major sevenths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminished_major_seventh_chord). In particular I'd just look into the various scale modes (e.g. Lydian) and pick out chords from there.
- If it's a slow horror song I'd suggest using a Dorian mode for parts of it - it'll evoke the same kind of felling as those medieval Latin sacred hymns.
- Maybe a whole tone scale for parts of it? Whole tone scales usually sound quite alien, with a blurred, indistinct effect.
- Sound design with esotoric instruments. Maybe the sound of breaking glass, or a guitar distorted in a certain way, or a children's xylophone, or a disonnant music box can help build a effect.
- Another thing you could try is a 20th century style atonal *tone row*. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0ECHSnzlME) is an example.
- Odd time signatures or changing time signatures are not usually used since they sound disjointed - which is perfect for horror music!

Comment: +1 Great list! Esoteric is a great word to keep in mind for this style. A few additional ideas: Tremolos, glissadi (esp. slow ones), tone clusters, and very low melodies (contrabass, contrabassoon, trombones, organ pedals). Also, the minor-major-seventh chord (e.g. C-Eb-G-B), aka the "Hitchcock chord".